# Green and Red arrows with numbers beside in Pycharm code completion window

Tags: autocomplete, pycharm, code-completion

There are some green upside arrows and red downside arrows with some numbers beside them in code completion window in Pycharm 2020.
I really don't have any clue what these arrows and numbers stand for.
You can see a sample of it in below image.
What is the meaning of the arrows and numbers?
Any help  would be appreciated.

[image: Green and Red arrows with numbers beside in Pycharm code completion window]

Comment: What exact version are you using? I've never seen those before.

Comment: I just updated to the latest version and I don't have those. Weird.

Comment: @Carcigenicate pycharm ver. 2020.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out this option is related to `Machine Learning Code Completion` plugin that is bundled with pycharm and is available via `Settings>Editor>General>Code Completion>Machine Learning-Assisted Completion>Rank completion suggestions based on Machine Learning`.
And this numbers are some sort of ranking.

Plugin doc says:

> The plugin improves code completion feature by reordering of elements in the completion popup by ranking more relevant items higher using machine learning.

Answer (score 1):

Those green ↑ or red ↓ has similar meaning as arrows used in foreign exchange rates:

[image]

but instead of rise / drop in the rate, they show rise / drop in *applying them to your code*.
(Consequently, more frequently used items are in higher positions in the completion popup.)

[image]